# MySQL data type for 128 bit integers

Tags: mysql, datatypes

I need to store 128 bits unsigned integers into MySQL and I was wondering what is the best data type to store such big numbers.

Right now, I'm using `binary(16)` but that involves a lot of conversion function `pack(/huge number in hex .../)`.

Is there a best datatype to store a 128 bit unsigned integer?

Comment: There are several dupes of this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444771/how-to-store-a-128-bit-number-in-a-single-column-in-mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120371/how-to-convert-ipv6-from-binary-for-storage-in-mysql

Answer (score 12):

I don't know what the best way necessarily is to store it -- but there's at least a better option than using a `varchar(39)` (or `varchar(40)` if you needed it signed) ; instead use a `decimal(39,0)`.  [From the mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html):

> **Fixed-Point (Exact-Value) Types**
>
> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store
>   exact numeric data values. These types
>   are used when it is important to
>   preserve exact precision, for example
>   with monetary data. In MySQL, NUMERIC
>   is implemented as DECIMAL, so the
>   following remarks about DECIMAL apply
>   equally to NUMERIC.
>
> MySQL 5.1 stores DECIMAL values in
>   binary format. Before MySQL 5.0.3,
>   they were stored as strings. See
>   Section 11.18, “Precision Math”.
>
> In a DECIMAL column declaration, the
>   precision and scale can be (and
>   usually is) specified; for example:
>
> ```
> salary DECIMAL(5,2)
> ```
>
> In this example, 5 is the precision
>   and 2 is the scale. The precision
>   represents the number of significant
>   digits that are stored for values, and
>   the scale represents the number of
>   digits that can be stored following
>   the decimal point.
>
> Standard SQL requires that
>   DECIMAL(5,2) be able to store any
>   value with five digits and two
>   decimals, so values that can be stored
>   in the salary column range from
>   -999.99 to 999.99.
>
> In standard SQL, the syntax DECIMAL(M)
>   is equivalent to DECIMAL(M,0).
>   Similarly, the syntax DECIMAL is
>   equivalent to DECIMAL(M,0), where the
>   implementation is permitted to decide
>   the value of M. MySQL supports both of
>   these variant forms of DECIMAL syntax.
>   The default value of M is 10.
>
> If the scale is 0, DECIMAL values
>   contain no decimal point or fractional
>   part.
>
> The maximum number of digits for
>   DECIMAL is 65, but the actual range
>   for a given DECIMAL column can be
>   constrained by the precision or scale
>   for a given column. When such a column
>   is assigned a value with more digits
>   following the decimal point than are
>   permitted by the specified scale, the
>   value is converted to that scale. (The
>   precise behavior is operating
>   system-specific, but generally the
>   effect is truncation to the
>   permissible number of digits.)

It's stored packed, so it'll take up less space than the varchar ([18 bytes, if I'm doing my math right](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html)), and I'd hope you'd be able to do math on it directly, but I've never tried with that large of a number to see what happens.

Answer (score 8):

I found myself asking this question and from all the posts I read never found any performance comparisons.  So here's my attempt.

I've created the following tables, populated with 2,000,000 random ip address from 100 random networks.

```
CREATE TABLE ipv6_address_binary (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    addr BINARY(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE ipv6_address_twobigints (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    haddr BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    laddr BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE uidx (haddr, laddr)
);

CREATE TABLE ipv6_address_decimal (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    addr DECIMAL(39,0) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Then I SELECT all ip addresses for each network and record the response time.  Average response time on the twobigints table is about 1 second while on the binary table it is about one-hundredth of a second.

Here are the queries.

> Note:
>
> X_[HIGH/LOW] is the most/least significant 64-bits of X
>
> when NETMASK_LOW is 0 the AND condition is omitted as it always yields true.  doesn't affect performance very much.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ipv6_address_twobigints
WHERE haddr & NETMASK_HIGH = NETWORK_HIGH
AND laddr & NETMASK_LOW = NETWORK_LOW

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ipv6_address_binary
WHERE addr >= NETWORK
AND addr <= BROADCAST

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ipv6_address_decimal
WHERE addr >= NETWORK
AND addr <= BROADCAST
```

Average response times:

[image: Average response times]

```
BINARY_InnoDB  0.0119529819489
BINARY_MyISAM  0.0139244818687
DECIMAL_InnoDB 0.017379629612
DECIMAL_MyISAM 0.0179929423332
BIGINT_InnoDB  0.782350552082
BIGINT_MyISAM  1.07809265852
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only other option is to store it in a `varchar(39)` field.

Comment: I think this would work if you only want to store the data.

Comment: @eiefai: ah ok, I misunderstood.  You're absolutely right, the value would have to be cast before it could be treated as a number.

Answer (score 0):

I use a base64 string that uses 22bytes (4 byte overhead).
The reason I do this, is just because every platform supports base64 and strings and is easy to work with.

I found no real performance gain between 22bytes and 18bytes on MySql and Oracle.
I did however found significant improvement when using two 64bit unsigned integers, but it's a pain to work with and unless performance is extremely critical I'd suggest just go with a single column and 22bytes.